# How to make circle on a current location in google map instead of marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How to make circle on a current location in google map instead of pointer.i am working on google map current location.Here is my code.Everything is working fine.I just want to point out the current location on a google map using a circle instead of pointer arrow.Here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAaczGkYJhz_uP1Xo03sWxYnBB7R1NXzZE&sensor=false&libraries=places&language=eng&types=establishment"></script>

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (p) {

  var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude,p.coords.longitude);

  var mapOptions = {
      center: LatLng,
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId:  google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP                      

  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

      position: LatLng,
      map: map,
      title: "<div style = 'height:60px;width:200px'><b>Your location:</b><br />Latitude: " + p.coords.latitude + "<br />Longitude: " + p.coords.longitude
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      infoWindow.setContent(marker.title);
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
});
```

what i have to modify in my code to do this.can any one help me please???can any one modify my code please???

i have already tried to modify my code  but it is not working

```
var circle = new google.maps.Marker({
                                            center: center,
                                            center: new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude, p.coords.longitude),
                                            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                                            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                                            strokeWeight: 2,
                                            fillColor: '#FF0000',
                                            fillOpacity: 0.35,
                                            map: map,
                                            position: LatLng,

                                          title: "<div style = 'height:60px;width:200px'><b>Your location:</b><br />Latitude: " + p.coords.latitude + "<br />Longitude: " + p.coords.longitude
                                        });
```

but it is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use `Circles` instead of a `Marker`. The Google Maps JS API has good documentation and samples on the same. [Link to sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple)

Make necessary changes within the Circle options object to make the circle look like you desire.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (p) {

  var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude,p.coords.longitude);

  var mapOptions = {
      center: LatLng,
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId:  google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP                      

  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

  // Commented out the marker
  /*var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: LatLng,
      map: map,
      title: "<div style = 'height:60px;width:200px'><b>Your location:</b><br />Latitude: " + p.coords.latitude + "<br />Longitude: " + p.coords.longitude
  });*/

  //Added the circle
  var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
              strokeColor: '#FF0000',
              strokeOpacity: 0.8,
              strokeWeight: 2,
              fillColor: '#FF0000',
              fillOpacity: 0.35,
              map: map,
              center: LatLng,
              radius: 100
            });

  // Removed Event listner on the marker as marker is not being used
  /*google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      infoWindow.setContent(marker.title);
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });*/
});
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: i have one question how to set the radius in this circle dynamically for the latitude longitude

Comment: @santanu just pass the dynamic variable to `radius: 100`. Have a variable holding the value and set it to `radius: myDynamicVar`

Comment: ok thanks.can you tell me how to find the exact location name from the latitude longitude.i know this is out of my question but i need this.

Comment: @santanu This is know as Reverse Geo Coding. Take a look at this sample here. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a "circular marker" instead of the default "bubble", you can use the [predefined SVG SymbolPath CIRCLE](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#SymbolPath):

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: LatLng,
  map: map,
  title: "<div style = 'height:60px;width:200px'><b>Your location:</b><br />Latitude: " + LatLng.lat() + "<br />Longitude: " + LatLng.lng(),
  icon: {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    fillColor: "blue",
    fillOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 0,
    scale: 10
  },
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/en28r176/)

[image]

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var infoWindow;

function initialize() {
  var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var mapOptions = {
    center: LatLng,
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: LatLng,
    map: map,
    title: "<div style = 'height:60px;width:200px'><b>Your location:</b><br />Latitude: " + LatLng.lat() + "<br />Longitude: " + LatLng.lng(),
    icon: {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
      fillColor: "blue",
      fillOpacity: 1,
      strokeColor: "blue",
      strokeOpacity: 1,
      strokeWeight: 0,
      scale: 10
    },
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    infoWindow.setContent(marker.title);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```